# Access macro to read emails from MS Outlook

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba, instance

I have a macro in Access that connects to the running instance of MS Outlook.

The macro had been working, until last week when I started receiving the error: **Activex component can't create object** whenever I ran the macro.

Here's a piece of the code and where it's currently failing:

```
Function GatherDailyStats()
Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
Dim oOlItm As Object
'Dim FileName As
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim strDir1 As String
Dim strDir2 As String
'~~> Get Outlook instance
Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '--**THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS**
Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders.Item("Daily Stats")

'~~> Check if there are any actual unread emails
If oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Daily Stats folder"
    Exit Function
End If
```

Nothing has changed in the code since I created it and tested it thoroughly.

---

Update: I just tested the same application on a different computer and it worked perfectly there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already tried those suggestions from Microsoft and none of them solved the issue.

Comment: I'll consider adding that information to the Question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a KB article about the ROT and how Office applications by design don't register until their start up sequence has finished.](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B238610&x=10&y=11.) You may be seeing an issue that was always there, just never ran into it before for whatever reason.

Lifted from [this discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/getobject-fails-with-outlook-2010/1ee65231-2118-4223-8c40-95a9680000f8?page=2) you may want to try adding a fall back to make sure that the application is running:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    End If
```

From that same discussion it is important to note that Outlook 2010 apparently has some kind of issue with registering in the ROT when not started in Administrator mode.

[Apparently there is a work around](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/isvvba/thread/da19d1be-f62e-4f0a-8bb8-d104dbc2a5b3) that someone has posted which includes:

> ...if you assign the Everyone group full rights to the Office install
>   directory it will then work.

Not sure that is the greatest idea but it is a known issue with Office 2010.

EDIT: [here is one last resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550).

Comment: I appreciate your response Pow-Ian, but unfortunately, and after trying to implement each one of these suggestions, I wasn't able to make it work again. The application keeps failing at either GetObject or CreateObject.

Comment: The GetObject command works perfectly if I use Excel.Application instead of Outlook.Application... could this be related to permissions/security? Keep in mind that I have already implemented the workaround of adding Everyone to the Office installation folder.

Comment: it is certainly a possibility. No one seems to know how to get outlook specifically out of the ROT. I have seen places where they suggest looking for Outlook.Application.14 for 2010 and so on, but this adds overhead consisting of having to check for individual versions.

Comment: I read about that too, and digging up I was able to find something referent to this error. I was able to make it run by adding the version of MS Outlook to the command (Outlook.Application.14) but still the GetObject doesn't work, so I have to run the macro with Outlook closed.

Answer (score 1):

GetObject will throw an error, if the application isn't running. You need to check for this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set oOlAp = New Outlook.Application
```

Alternatively, you could just create a new instance of your object:

```
Set oOlAp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Using `CreateObject` to create a new instance will, of course, increase resource load in cases when an object of same type was already initialized. Saying it differently, to increase performance and lower use of system resources, better use the first suggested solution.

Comment: Thank you, but neither GetObject nor CreateObject work and both are throwing exact same error, whether Outlook is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, always use CreateObject when creating an instance of the Outlook.Application object - Outlook is a singleton, so only one instance will ever be running for the logged in user.
Secondly, what are the versions of Outlook and Access? Are they all the same version>? If not, are they both 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thank for your response, but I slightly disagree. I can prove you that for MS outlook 2010 more than one instance can be running at the same time. Anyway, they both are 2012, 32.

Comment: Only if they are running in different user contexts or if one of the instances hanged and another instance is waiting for the hanged instance to come back alive.